# How to push object straight in game engine

Tags: game-engine, physics

How can I push an object in a straight line with another object in the game engine? I made both objects dynamic, but when I push the object it moves in a random way. So how can I make it move straight?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6115/599

Answer (score 2):

Your collision bounds on both objects are a sphere. Under the Physic tab check the button for "Collision Bounds". Now assuming you two objects are cubes, the cube collision bounds will work fine.

Comment: @mar_dim if that answered your question mark the answer as accepted (check mark button under the arrows)