# how can I accurately simulate ballistic physics?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I am trying to find out how to make a cannon or gun that works with the physics simulation. but I have two problems.

1. I'm not sure how to suddenly apply force behind an object,then remove it.
2. I can't stop the projectile from wedging into the barrel and bouncing around trying to escape.(the alternative is to make is smaller, but it still "bleeds" through the mesh)

how can I use the ridged physics engine to create a ballistic simulation( mortar, gun,etc)?

Comment: gandalf3 found the real solution (just below my user icon), I left the bad one here for fun. have a magical day this video + some imagination should do the trick. the video shows one object being animated into another one which freely moves as a rigid body. copy this but have the first object(the animated one) be an invisible object that is overlayed with an explosion. make the second object your bullet. skip to 1:15 to see the effect im talking about. also keep in mind that along with changing the speed of the pushing object, you can change the mass of either object to alter the speed of the

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5100/599 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8483/599 for animation based initial velocity/activation.

Comment: does this both stop funky collision detection and allow the force to be added at any time during the sim or only at the beginning?

Comment: @user16973 Hm.. Unfortunately my comment was deleted somehow, but I linked some posts about both. Here are the links again: [post 1](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5100/how-can-i-add-motion-to-an-object?lq=1), [post 2](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1811/tips-for-making-mesh-rigid-body-collision-shapes-more-stable?lq=1), [post 3](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6115/unexpected-reactions-in-a-quiet-simple-rigidbody-physics-simulation?lq=1), [post 4](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8483/activate-physics-by-keyframe?lq=1).

Comment: If those don't answer your question, then feel free to either leave a comment on one of the answers, or post another question if you feel the other questions aren't the asking same question you are. Also try to keep your questions to one question per post :)