# Rigid body collision not precise

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I'm new to Blender and have been playing with rigid body simulations. I have noticed that collisions are not very accurate, which is usually okay, but, in this instance, it makes objects fly through each other.

[image: img1]

This simulation moved the plane upwards, smashing a cylinder into pieces. Note that there are pieces below the plane which didn't perform collision checks correctly. How can such occurrences be prevented?

Comment: It really depends on your particular scene and setup. It's hard to say what specific steps you can take without looking at your file, but there are some tips in [this post](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1811/599).

Comment: You could try sub-dividing the mesh once or twice to start with.  Maybe more if it's needed.  You could also try increasing the thickness of the plane.  If you upload your .blend file it will be easier for someone to hone in on the error.

Comment: @Mirac7 If your problem is solved, we can mark this as a duplicate of [Tips for making Mesh Rigid-body collision shapes more stable](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1811/599). This way other visitors can find the answer more easily.

Comment: @gandalf3 Agreed.