# Why is this passive rigid body allowing objects to pass through it?

Tags: objects, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I have an object falling to the ground and breaking into pieces, but my plane, which is a passive rigid body, allows many pieces to pass through it:

[image: Before]

[image: In The Animation]

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6):

Planes are notoriously bad objects to use as solid collision objects.
I would suggest to use a cube, with a cube bounding box.

Comment: Agreed. Pop a very subtle solidify on there and see if you get better results.

Comment: How to make a Cube with A Cube bounding box ?

Comment: Switch "Shape" from Rigid Body Options from Mesh to Box

Answer (score 6):

You can add a collision margin on the plane (the passive rigid body).

Also, increasing the number of simulation steps per frame from the rigid body properties panel in Scene properties tab will give you better results.

Comment: Increasing the number of steps did the trick (for a box), thanks!

Comment: I encountered this in blender 3.2.2. The settings have moved to Properties > Scene tab > Rigid Body World > "Substeps per frame" and "Solver Iterations". For my usecase I had to increase them to 15 and 150 respectively to get clipping down to an acceptable level.

Comment: @PLATO where the heck is this option?!?! Could you please share a screenshot?

Comment: Here it is: https://imgur.com/a/Z3nD9S1

Answer (score 0):

In the Rigid settings pannel, if you are using a plane or a cube, change the default *Convex Hull* in *Collisions* shape to box, so it simulates the collision of a cube