# Blender objects pass through the ground

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I was working on a Blender project on objects falling to the ground. I set the ground to "passive" and the objects to "active". After doing the simulation, I noticed how some of the objects just fall through the ground and the rest just land on the ground.

There were other things that I did along the way: baking the simulations and moving the objects a little higher from the ground.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, so I hope somebody has that kind of problem and would be able to help me :).

Comment: see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40361/object-falls-though-other-objects-even-when-given-the-same-physics?noredirect=1&lq=1 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1811/tips-for-making-mesh-rigid-body-collision-shapes-more-stable?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I assume you haven't baked a simulation and then moved the ground, as in that case the objects would retain the baked simulation and not recalculate for the new ground position. Sometimes the simulation frames combined with the object movement means that the objects go through the floor between frames and therefore don't interact, in which case slowing down the simulation (e.g. reduce gravity or increase steps - see Sazerac's link) can solve the problem. Also try changing the Physics/Rigid/Shape to see if that solves it.