# Why do my bricks topple over?

Tags: physics

I scaled the standard cube to be 2 x 1 x .5, created several copies of it and moved these around so that they *should* not topple over according to the laws of physics for the following reason:

[image]

- The center of gravity (COG) of the top brick is at x = -1.349, the second brick extends from x = -1.449 to +0.551, hence should nicely carry the top brick.
- The COG of the top two bricks together is at x = (-1.349 -0.449)/2 = -0.899, the third brick extends from -0.949 to +1.051, hence should nicely carry the top two bricks.
- The COG of the top three bricks is at x = (-1.349 -0.449 +0.051)/3 = -0.582333..., the fourth brick extends from -.616 to +1.384, hence should nicely carry the top three bricks.
- The COG of the top four bricks is at x =  (-1.349 -0.449 +0.051 +0.384)/4 = -0.34075, the fifth brick extends from -.366 to +1.634, hence should nicely carry the top four bricks.
- The COG of the top five bricks is at x =  (-1.349 -0.449 +0.051 +0.384 +0.634)/5 = -0.1458, the sixth brick extends from -.166 to +1.834, hence should nicely carry the top five bricks.
- The COG of all six bricks is at x =  (-1.349 -0.449 +0.051 +0.384 +0.634 +0.834)/6 = +0.0175, the floor plane extends from x = 0 upward, hence should nicely carry the bricks.

Nevertheless, if I run the animation, the bricks start to topple and three of them fall down to negative infinity ...

Is this a problem of the blender physics engine that it cannot deal with such fragile balancing? Or did I do something wrong in the modelling?

Comment: Apply scale to all objects and use a cube for your floor/collision instead of a plane.

Comment: @Dontwalk Scale *is* applied (shows as 1.0000 for X, Y, and Z in the `N` pane). And the toppling also happens if I use the bottom brick as floor (by setting its physics to "Passive")

Comment: I think the "top" brick is simply hanging too far out. If I delete it (top brick) and set the "Steps" to 400 the animation is perfectly stable. This may help https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1811/tips-for-making-mesh-rigid-body-collision-shapes-more-stable

Comment: @Dontwalk Of course the whole point is that the ensemble is *barely* stable (but according to the rules of classical physics it definitely is stable with sufficient safety margin for numerical imprecision) and removing the top brick defies the purpose. -- But the "Steps per Second" (with all bricks still there) really did it: 200 give only a short tremble in the beginning, 300 and more make it almost unnoticeable (on the other hand, 20 looks like an earthquake and one brick even falls through the floor). -- I suggest you turn the Steps-hint into an answer ...

Comment: Thank you. But the way this forum works is that if the steps link solved it for you it's already been answered by that previous post and a Moderator should mark this post as a Duplicate. Happy Blendering :)