# Active meshes keep bouncing and slipping away from passive meshes

Tags: mesh, physics, rigid-body-simulation

Attached here is a link to a video of a problem that I am addressing.

https://youtu.be/GE4nFNFLEZA

I am working on this render, and I applied the "passive" rigid body tool to both the ground and that holder thing that I created. And I applied the "active" rigid body tool for my spheres.

When I baked the physics and played it after the baking, the spheres seem to bounce around and slide away unnaturally.

I'm not sure how I can solve this, and I bet you guys can help me out with this.

Comment: If you've baked the physics, have you also switched the physics properties off?  In addition, check the Dopesheet and rid it of any physics strips that might be still there. (highlite the strip at extreme left and press X)

Once 'live' physics are gone you're left with the baked keyframes and can delete those that are still 'trembling'.

Comment: read this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1811/tips-for-making-mesh-rigid-body-collision-shapes-more-stable  and try to follow. sometimes it's enough to triangulate the mesh, sometimes just changing the collision margin or collision shape, or even just scaling things up will do.