# Two closely fitting angular blocks

Tags: physics, collision

How to get the correct and expected behavior of this two blocks, falling down one on another? With using rigid body physics. The default collisions seems not act as you expext.

Please, feel free to ask question if my description is not clear to you.
Thank's.

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1811/tips-for-making-mesh-rigid-body-collision-shapes-more-stable

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos this is not helped. The practical example would be more useful and understandable.

Comment: Hello and welcome. "*This is not helped.*" Why? Saying "it didn't help" without details about what you have tried and where it failed doesn't really give us any hints on how to help you. Sounds like you just didn't try the solutions in the linked posts. Your question is also devoid of any details about how you setup your scene, physics, simulations etc. Please provide factual information about your situation we can use to diagnose the issue rather than blindly guess around what you missed.

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos it seems this case is the fundamental problem. It's just two basic cubes with cutted corner on the side. It shouldn't take a lot of effort to make it act properly.
You can model this by your hand in a couple of seconds. Convex hull collision shape does not ensure expected result, as well as mesh shape. If you find the way of how it could be solved with a less effort, please share. 
May be I don't know something.